# How to get input from Output tab in NetBeans

Tags: netbeans, input, io

I have an Output tab created and I would like to listen for user's input (to do a chat like component). Of course you can't predict when the user is going to type.

I found the org.jivesoftware.smack.util package and the related ObservableReader and ReaderListener that should do the trick, but I'm missing something and can't figure it out... yet.

Here's the code I have:

```
/*
 * Enable/create the tabs we need for the component
 */
package sample.component;

import com.dreamer.outputhandler.OutputHandler;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.util.ObservableReader;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.util.ReaderListener;
import org.openide.modules.ModuleInstall;

/**
 * Manages a module's lifecycle. Remember that an installer is optional and
 * often not needed at all.
 */
public class Installer extends ModuleInstall implements ReaderListener {

    private final String normal = "Output";

    @Override
    public void restored() {
        OutputHandler.output(normal, "Welcome! Type something below.");
        OutputHandler.setInputEnabled(normal, true);
        ObservableReader reader = new ObservableReader(OutputHandler.getReader(normal));
        reader.addReaderListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void read(String read) {
        System.out.println("Read: " + read);
        OutputHandler.output(normal, "You typed: " + read);
    }
}
```

OutPutHandler is a helper class I created to handle the output tabs. You can see its source [here](http://java.net/projects/output-handler/sources/source/content/src/com/dreamer/outputhandler/OutputHandler.java?rev=5)

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got it! It was a mix of the above code with [this](http://forums.netbeans.org/ptopic37223.html) forum post and this classes: org.jivesoftware.smack.util.ObservableReader and org.jivesoftware.smack.util.ReaderListener. See the FAQ [here](http://wiki.netbeans.org/wiki/index.php?title=DevFaqInput&action=edit&redlink=1)

Comment: Solution is implemented in this NetBeans plugin: http://java.net/projects/output-handler